# iOS: Is there a way to check if an NSArray object contains a certain character?

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, nsarray

I need a way to know if an array has the character "@" in one of its string objects. The following code obviously doesn't work because it checks if an object just has the @ sign instead of checking if an object contains the @ sign. For example, if the user has test@test.com my if statement won't detect it. I need to see if a user has an email or not. I tried researching on how to accomplish this on stackoverflow, but no luck. Any tips or suggestions will be appreciated.

```
if([answer containsObject:@"@"]){
  /// do function.                 
}
```

Comment: Maybe something with `NSPredicate`?

Comment: What kind of objects are in your array?

Comment: If the objects are NSString (as your sample suggests), you can use `rangeOfString:` to detect a substring.

Comment: NSString, sorry for not specifying.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check if an NSArray contains an object with `containsObject`.  If it's an array of characters represented as one-character strings, then the code is simple:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d"];
BOOL contains = [array containsObject:@"c"];
```

There's no such thing as an NSArray of scalar types like 'c' char, since the NS collections contain only objects.  The nearest thing to an array of chars is an `NSString`, which has a variety of ways to tell you if a character is present.  The simplest looks like this:

```
NSString *string = @"test@test.com";
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"c"];
BOOL contains = range.location != NSNotFound;
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to cycle through each NSString in the array and check if it contains the substring.

This custom method shows how:

```
//assumes all objects in the array are NSStrings
- (BOOL)array:(NSArray *)array containsSubstring:(NSString *)substring {

    BOOL containsSubstring = NO;

    for (NSString *string in array) {

        if ([string rangeOfString:substring].location != NSNotFound) {
            containsSubstring = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    return containsSubstring;
}
```

Usage:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
[array addObject:@"hi"];
[array addObject:@"yo"];
[array addObject:@"test@test.com"];

BOOL containsSubstring = [self array:array containsSubstring:@"@"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom Category class of NSArray and add the following method:

```
- (BOOL) containsCharacter:(NSString *) character
{
    BOOL characterFound = NO;
    for (id object in self)
    {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
            NSRange range = [object rangeOfString:character];
            if (range.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                characterFound = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return characterFound;
}
```

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: also a great option. To make a category: File > New File > Objective-C Category > Set Category name to whatever and then select NSArray for the class

Answer (score 0):

I think that is better way - to use predicates for filtering your array as [Larme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme) said.

Try something like this:

```
NSArray *answer = @[@"John Appleseed", @"john@apple.com", @"john@icloud.com", @"+14120123456", @"invalid@email", @"another@@@invalid.email"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [answer filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS \"@\""]];
if (filteredArray.count > 0) {
    // Do something
}
```

The filteredArray will contains all objects, which contains at-symbol:

```
john@apple.com,
john@icloud.com,
invalid@email,
another@@@invalid.email
```

Another way - is to filter array by valid email strings and not only at-symbol:

```
NSArray *answer = @[@"John Appleseed", @"john@apple.com", @"john@icloud.com", @"+14120123456", @"invalid@email", @"another@@@invalid.email"];
NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSArray *filteredArray = [answer filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]];
if (filteredArray.count > 0) {
    // Do something
}
```

The filteredArray will contains only objects, which matches to email-mask

```
john@apple.com,
john@icloud.com
```